# How to pull data from a web page that shows only the first 500 rows out of 7,000 + rows into PowerBI?

Tags: excel, powerbi

There is a web page that contains data of over 7000 rows of data. It obviously doesn't show all of them unless you extract the data to excel. However, I want it to auto refresh from the web page into PowerBI every day and I can't do that if it isn't reading all the data.

I tried linking excel to the web page and the same problem occurs. It will only read the first 800 rows because that is what the website displays. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: See https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/